# Clearing text boxes inside of a Control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a series of of tabs that hold text boxes in them.  Some of the tabs have a control that contains Text Boxes inside of a Scrollview as well.  I am trying to iterate through the tabs and clear the content of the text boxes.

I was going to use this:

```
foreach(TabItem item in Tabs.Items)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(this);
}
```

I then use this to clear to the text boxes:

```
TextBox tb = obj as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
tb.Text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i));
}
```

It is currently only clearing the first tab and none of the rest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LogicalTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.aspx). Only the items of the currently active tab are contained in the visual tree, therefore the visual tree helper is not the best choice for your task.

Iterating over the tab items is IMO not necessary, only if you have a lot of other controls not residing in the tab-items and therefore want to spare cpu power. As already mentioned by Bela R, there is an error in your call to ClearTextBoxes().

Comment: +1 - I had many issues with the TabControl until I realized that only the currently selected Tab has it's control's loaded.

Comment: I changed it over to ClearTextBoxes(Tabs) and it worked for the current tab...how would I use LogicalTreeHelper in this situation...I am not all that familiar with it.

Comment: @Woundedbear: The following link contains a helper method that looks in the logical and in the visual tree. With this you will find all elements. I have not tested it but it looks ok. http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/06/finding-elements-in-wpf-tree-both-ways  If my answer has helped you, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark under the voting buttons of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `ClearTextBoxes(item)` and not `ClearTextBoxes(this)`

```
foreach(TabItem item in Tabs.Items)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(item);
}
```